# use another data structure instead of seccomp_data with seccomp

Tags: bpf, seccomp

Is it possible to use another data structure instead of seccomp_data within the BPF code of seccomp?
For example from this...

```
...
BPF_STMT(BPF_LD+BPF_W+BPF_ABS,(offsetof (struct seccomp_data, args[0]))),
...
```

to this

```
...
BPF_STMT(BPF_LD+BPF_W+BPF_ABS,(offsetof (struct my_data, my_field[0]))),
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that structure is [populated on the kernel side](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.4-rc8/source/kernel/seccomp.c#L806) before calling your cBPF program. To change what data your cBPF programs take as input, you'd have to edit (and recompile) the kernel.

You could redefine that structure, but I'm not sure what the point of that would be.

Comment: How can I see the cascade of functions called by the kernel when "seccomp is triggered" by a system call?

Comment: Bootlin (link in answer) should allow you to do that. On x86, you go through `do_syscall_64`, `syscall_trace_enter`, and `__secure_computing`.

Comment: thanks, but how do_syscall_64 and do_seccomp are related? I mean do_seccomp should be the common entry point both for prctl and seccomp system calls, does it trigger do_syscall_64?

Comment: I expect `do_syscall_64` to be called for all x86-64 syscalls, so yes, even for `seccomp` and `prctl`, when installing a new seccomp filter for instance.